# Csv button won't appear in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datatables

I have this django HTML template with usage of datatables table:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load dictionary_extras %}
{% block title %}QA reports - {{report_title}}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    tfoot {
    display: table-header-group;
    }
</style>

<h1>{{report_title}}<br>
    <small>(created on: {{report_creation_time}})</small>
</h1>

<table id='report_data' class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        {% for col_name in report_data_headers%}
        <th>{{col_name}}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        {% for col_name in report_data_headers%}
        <th>{{col_name}}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
    {% for data_row in report_data%}
    <tr>
        {% for item in data_row%}
        <td>{{item}}</td>
        {% endfor%}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>$(document).ready(function() {

        // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
        $('#report_data tfoot th').each( function () {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
        } );

        // DataTable
        var table = $('#report_data').DataTable({
            "aLengthMenu": [[20, 50, 100, -1],
                            [20, 50, 100, "All"]],
            "buttons": ['csv']
        });

        // Apply the search
        table.columns().every( function () {
            var that = this;

            $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                    that
                        .search( this.value )
                        .draw();
                }
            } );
        } );
    } );
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

I follow this [datatables tutorial](https://datatables.net/reference/button/csv)

My problem is that I can't make the **datatables csv button** appear on the page. I ask for this option in `"buttons": ['csv']` line. Tried different options with and without quotation marks with no luck - the datatable displays as if the "buttons" line is not present in the code. Is there a syntax problem with my code?

Comment: The buttons will not appear my magic. You must at least include the Buttons plugin source code and instruct dataTables to use buttons, either through the `dom` option or by a button instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simply missing some script files (specifically the buttons extension file and the JSZip file (which is required for the `csv`/`excel` buttons specifically). I'd recommend going to the [DataTables download builder](https://datatables.net/download/index), which will allow you to pick the extensions you want and will then give you a nice download package to include the script files you need.

I quickly generated this list below which contains just those script files required for DataTables and the `csv` button:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
```

I wouldn't recommend just copy/pasting this script (instead use it as an example) but instead go to the [DataTables download builder](https://datatables.net/download/index) and ensure you have the required scripts (remember you MUST have JSzip for HTML5 export to csv.